# installing i18n_routing on heroku (i18n requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, internationalization, heroku

I try to deploy my first app on heroku.

I've created a gem manifest file which include:
i18n_routing --version '0.3.3'

When I push to heroku, all the gems are installed but i18n:

-----> Installing gem i18n_routing 0.3.3 from http://rubygems.org
       ERROR:  Error installing i18n_routing:
        i18n requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

How can I update RubyGems on heroku ?
Is there anything I'm missing here ? :-)

Thanks for your answers.

Fro_oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to Sebastien Gruhier for the explanation and the solution :-)

I've migrated my app on a new Stack: bamboo-ree-1.8.7
http://docs.heroku.com/stack